# TypeScript: Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-thunk

I have the following redux-thunk action creator:

```
function updateInitiator(form_request_id, { to_recipient }) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    const url = `/some/url`;
    const data = { to_recipient };

    return fetch(url, { method: 'PUT', body: JSON.stringify(data) }).then(() => {
      dispatch(fetchResponses());
    });
  };
}
```

Then I declare the type of the function:

```
type UpdateInitiator = typeof updateInitiator;
```

I'm trying to derive the type of a bound thunk action. In short, when the action creator is "bound" in react-redux, it automatically calls the function returned with `dispatch` and then returns the return result of *that* internal function. I'm trying to declare a type for this behavior. It works if I do it without generics:

```
type BoundUpdateInitiator = (...args: Parameters<UpdateInitiator>) => ReturnType<ReturnType<UpdateInitiator>>;
```

But when I try to declare a generic type for any bound function, I'm having some trouble:

```
type BoundThunk<T> = (...args: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<ReturnType<T>>;
type BoundUpdateInitiator = BoundThunk<UpdateInitiator>;
```

This gives me the error:

```
error TS2344: Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'.

236 type BoundThunk<T> = (...args: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<ReturnType<T>>;
                                              ~

error TS2344: Type 'ReturnType<T>' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'.
  Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '(...args: any) => any'.
    Type '{}' provides no match for the signature '(...args: any): any'.

236 type BoundThunk<T> = (...args: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<ReturnType<T>>;
                                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

error TS2344: Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'.

236 type BoundThunk<T> = (...args: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<ReturnType<T>>;
                                                                           ~
```

I can vaguely understand that `T` might be things other than a function, and similarly `ReturnType<T>` might also not be a function, and this generic type maybe doesn't account for those cases. I'm having trouble understanding how I *can* account for them, however. Ideally by not allowing them. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is what generic type constraints are for. Look at the definitions of `ReturnType<T>` and `Parameters<T>` and you'll immediately see what you have to write. Ex: `type BoundThunk<T extends (...args: any[]) => any> = (...args: Parameters<T>) => stuff`

Comment: @AluanHaddad that did the trick. If you want to make an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In order to accomplish this we would use a generic type constraint.

This is in fact how the type parameters of the language provided utility types `Parameters<T>` and `ReturnType<T>` are themselves specified and thus produce the error you receive.

In order to instantiate a generic type, say `ReturnType<T>`, with our type parameter, our type parameter must constrained at least as restrictively as the type parameter named `T` in `ReturnType<T>`.

By looking at the declaration of `ReturnType<T>`, as provided by the containing `lib` file, we can determine the minimum constraint we must apply to our own type and also find an example of the proper syntax for expressing said constraint.

```
type ReturnType<T extends (...args: any[]) => any> =
    // details
```

Don't worry about the implementation (after the `=`) as that is a broader topic. In this situation, we will focus on the constraints of `T` specificied using the `extends` keyword at the declaration of `T`.

Therefore, in order to pass the `T` declared by `BoundThunk<T>` to `ReturnType<T>` we must constrain it to meet the requirements above (note that `Parameters<T>` has identical constraints).

```
type BoundThunk<T extends (...args: any[]) => any> =
    (...args: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<ReturnType<T>>;
```

However, our requirements for `T` are actually *more* restrictive because we apply `ReturnType<T>` twice, `ReturnType<ReturnType<T>>`, implying that `T` is a higher order function, in this case a function that returns a function.

We will therefore refine our constraint accordingly

```
type BoundThunk<T extends (...args: any[]) => (...args: any[]) => any> =
    (...args: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<ReturnType<T>>;
```

Via the above adjustment, which further constrains `T` to be some function which returns another function, we allow ourselves to write `ReturnType<ReturnType<T>>`.

Comment: thanks for the thorough response! Is there any way to declare the type without using `any`? It doesn't look like it, but I was curious. In general I know it's ideal to use a more specific type than `any`, though in this case it doesn't look like it gets propagated anywhere.

Comment: Yes, you absolutely can use a more specific type like `T extends (s: string, b: boolean) => number` and that is a good idea if we have more information. It's worth noting however, that the `any`s above don't actually result in a function that takes any arguments and returns a result of type `any` they just allow the BoundThunk type to be a applied to any function that returns another function. Basically `any` doesn't remove type information when used in a constraint, it makes the constraint less specific. Constraints are like super types

Comment: hot damn, @AluanHaddad, these are some big brain plays